# How can I open Chrome from the command line with specific pages in tabs in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome

From the command line in Mac OS X, how can I open Google Chrome with a specific list of URLs open in tabs, with certain ones pinned?

Answer (score 67):

There is simpler way to open applications in Mac OS

```
open -a "Google Chrome" http://stackoverflow.com http://wikipedia.org
```

Answer (score 25):

An alias to open Chrome:

> `alias chrome="/Applications/Google\\ \\Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ \\Chrome"`

An alias to open Chrome with 2 given pages in tabs:

> `alias chromex="chrome --pinned-tab-count=2 http://www.google.com http://www.microsoft.com"`

Open the 2 pinned pages

> `chromex`

Comment: The `--pinned-tab-count` flag has since been removed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37596.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, I have scripts that do it like this:

```
open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app http://google.com http://stackoverflow.com
```